# Автопрокрутка содержимого в ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

В ScrollView находиться TextView с большим текстом.

На панели инструментов есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую текст должен 
автоматически двигаться вверх, постепенно показывая весь текст.
Можно ли это реализовать и как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860791/7609373, нужно гуглить, это ваш основной инструмент как у разработчика

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Это не совсем то, что  я искал. По-видимому, я не точно описал, что мне нужно получить.  Текст не быстро прокручиваться а медленно, при этом скорость его прокрутки должна регулироваться, к примеру SeekBar’ом.