# Как реализовать авто прокрутку в Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: java, android

Например:
У меня есть 10 ImageView которые находятся в LinearLayout который находится в Horizontal Scroll View. Я хочу чтобы каждые 2-3 секунды они автоматом прокручивались заменяя друг друга. Заранее благодарю за ответ))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/979197/238266

Comment: можно сделать это на viewpager, который будет автоматически переключать страницы, либо как здесь описано http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/imageswitcher.php